# Integral paradox in electric field from uniform charge density

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

When computing electric field of uniform charge density I get
the integral of form 
$$\int_{R^3} d^3 x' ~ \frac{\textbf x  - \textbf x'}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|^3} 
=\int_{R^3} d^3 r' ~ \frac{\textbf r'}{r'^3}  = 0 .$$
On the other hand when I use 
$$
 \int d^3 x' ~ \frac{\textbf x  - \textbf x'}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|^3} 
= - \nabla \int d^3 x' ~ \frac{1}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|},
$$
and using 
$$
 \frac{1}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|} = 4\pi \sum_{\ell m} \frac{1}{2l+1} \frac{r_<^l}{r^{l+1}_>} Y^*_{lm} (\hat x)Y_{lm} (\hat x'),
$$
it follows
$$
 \int_0^R x'^2 dx' \int d\Omega' ~ \frac{1}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|} 
= (4 \pi)^{3/2} \sum_{\ell m} \frac{1}{2l+1} Y^*_{lm} (\hat x)   \delta_{\ell0} \delta_{m0}  \int_0^R x'^2 dx'  \frac{r_<^l}{r^{l+1}_>} \\
= 4 \pi \left( \int_0^x x'^2 dx'  \frac{1}{x} + \int_x^R x'^2  \frac{1}{x'} dx'  \right) \\
= 4 \pi \left(  \frac{1}{2} R^2 - \frac{1}{6} x^2 \right).
$$
Collecting it all we have
$$
 \int d^3 x' ~ \frac{\textbf x  - \textbf x'}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|^3} 
=  - \nabla \int d^3 x' ~ \frac{1}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|} 
= - 4 \pi \nabla  \left(  \frac{1}{2} R^2 - \frac{1}{6} x^2 \right) 
= \frac{4 \pi }{3} \textbf x .
$$
Which is different from the first equation above. What is wrong here?

$\textbf{Edit I}$

Using the relation (Jackson eq (1.31))

$$ \nabla^2 \frac{1}{|\textbf x - \textbf x'|} = 
- 4\pi \delta(\textbf x - \textbf x')$$

we get

$$ \nabla \cdot \int d^3 x' ~ \frac{\textbf x  - \textbf x'}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|^3} =
- \nabla^2 \int d^3 x' ~ \frac{1}{|\textbf x  - \textbf x'|} =  4\pi, $$

which is consistent with the second result above, implying the first one might be wrong?

$\textbf{Edit II}$

Alternative derivation starting from
$$
\nabla^2 \phi(\textbf r) = 4 \pi \rho_0 e^{-\kappa r}
$$
which has a solution
$$
\phi_\kappa(\textbf r) = \rho_0  \int d^3 r' ~\frac{e^{-\kappa r'}}{|\vec r - \vec r'|} = \frac{\rho_0}{2 \pi^2} \int d^3 r' ~e^{-\kappa r'} 
  \int d^3 k \frac{1}{k^2} e^{-i \vec k \cdot (\vec r - \vec r')} \\
= 16 \rho_0 \int d k ~ j_0 (k r) \frac{\kappa}{k^2 + \kappa^2}
= \frac{4 \pi  \rho_0}{\kappa ^3 r}
\left( 2 - e^{ - \kappa r} ( 2 + \kappa r) \right) \\
= 4\pi  \rho_0 \left( \frac{1}{\kappa ^2} -\frac{1}{6} r^2 + \frac{1}{12} \kappa  r^3 + \ldots \right),
$$
perfect.  We have in $\kappa \to 0$ limit $ \textbf E = -\nabla \phi = \frac{4\pi}{3} \textbf r$. That looks consistent with the second approach.

Comment: The first integral is divergent, so even a physicist should hesitate to shift the variable of integration. In particular it is not zero, even as a principal value integral. The problem would probably disappear if you considered the integral as being over a large finite volume and took the limit.

Comment: How come I can not do something like $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int d^3 r ~ \textbf r / (r^3 +\epsilon )$?

Comment: Because the integral also diverges for large values of $r$, so you need to regulate both small and large $r$. The small-$r$ singularity is not strong enough to impede integrability anyway, since it is bounded by $1/r^2$.

Comment: Ok how about than $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int d^3 r ~ \frac{\textbf r}{r^3+\epsilon} e^{ - \epsilon r^2}$? This should be quite regular now... and gives back the initial integral in the limit.

Comment: @z.v. Technically you need two different regularisation parameters there. Watch also for dimensional consistency; you might want to write the parameters in terms of characteristic length scales.

Comment: @J.G. a yes right, that makes sence. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that it is clear that there can be no direction for the electric field to point in because of symmetry and that one need to be careful very careful with the singularity.

In your first approach, this works out because the shift of ${\bf x}$ to the origin, you impose the symmetry directly on the integral and the electric field from opposite sides cancels immediately.

In the second approach there is you need to be careful with the expansion you use for $\frac{1}{|{\bf x}-{\bf x'}|}$, which is valid only for $|{\bf x}| \neq |{\bf x}'|$. In the case of equality it does not converge, but you actually don't need it because you can use a spherical Gauss surface to compute the radially directed electric field.

If you take the integral $\int_0^\mu$ with $\mu<|{\bf x}|$ you obtain $\frac{4 \pi}{3} \mu^3 \frac{1}{x}$ which is just the potential due to all charge within a sphere of radius $\mu$ and contributes $\frac{4 \pi \mu^3}{3 x^2} \hat{x}~~~$ to the electric field.

The outside integral $\int_\nu^R$ with $|{\bf x}|<\nu$ gives a contribution $\frac{4 \pi}{3} (R^3 - \nu^3)$ to the potential, which does not depend on $x$ at all and hence does not result in any electric field. This is true for any homogenous spherical shell or more generally and radially symmetric charge distribution and I am sure it has been told/explained in one of the lectures.

So what is with the discrepancy between these two different outcomes? If we consider the direction you get for the electric field in the second approach, you notice that is is directed radially outwards with respect to the origin of the system. This would, however suggest that the direction of the electric field that is experienced at the point ${\bf x}$ would depend on the chosen reference frame. This is clearly unphysical and hence there can not or better there should not be such an electric field.

There is however a difference between the first and second approach and it is a rather subtle one. In the first case you consider the point ${\bf x}$ in the centre of a homogenous sphere of radius $R$ and take the limit $R \rightarrow \infty$. In the second case you consider a sphere of radius $R$ that is not centered around ${\bf x}$.

As long as you perform the calculation on an identical charge density distributions (finite values of $R$) with respect to the point ${\bf x}$, both methods will give the same answer. If you consider a spherical distribution centered at ${\bf x}$ the field will be zero in the first approach and the second approach has a correction from a the shell far away at distance $R$. The reason being that there are no complete spherical shells near the border. The electric field contribution of a small charge density element there is proportional to $\frac{1}{R^2}$, but at the same time the shell also has a volume proportional to $R^2$. This combination will give a finite contribution that will counteract the electric field from the spherical charge distribution for $|{\bf x'}| < |{\bf x}|$.

In the alternative version where there is a homogenous spherical charge density of radius $R$ but ${\bf x}$ is not placed in the center, it is the first approach that needs to be corrected for the border region and gets an overall non-zero electric field contribution. For any finite charge density this problem never occurs, but for infinite charge densities the results can depend on how you take the limit.

From the physics point of view we would argue that the electric field in the infinite system is not allowed to depend on the choice of reference frame. This does, however, not imply that there is no electrostatic force in the system, but merely that it has no particular direction and therefore is isotropic. It is a pressure like force that would like to increase the distance between all charge density elements by means of a homogenous expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I've been trying now for a while to estimate the contribution of the $\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}$ shell but I keep getting zero (I'll try to put an edit to the question with some of this). But what got me thinking a bit that the spherical solution is actually the correct one is the gauss law, i.e. $\nabla \cdot \textbf E = 4 \pi \rho$, that would imply the second solution might actually the correct one.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty in my initial answer which was wrong. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Sorry I had to digest it for a while. Why do you say we consider a shell not centered around $\textbf x$ in the second approach?

Comment: No problem, this is not an obvious thing at all.In the second approach we use the spherical coordinate system ${\bf x}'$ to integrate over the charge density  and we split it in two parts by $\int_0^R d {\bf x}' = \int_0^x d {\bf x}' + \int_x^R d {\bf x}'$. Hence we chose ${\bf x}$ to lie away from the centre of the sphere and get an $x$ dependent potential and a non-zero electric field. Only if you take the limit $x \rightarrow 0$ the term $\frac{2 \pi}{3}x^3$ in the potential that gives the electric field will vanish.

Comment: ok, thanks! I think I got it now (I hope :-)), in the first approach I think we implicitly use translation invariance to claim each point can be thought of as a center of a sphere, while in the second approach we do not use it and hence the obtained result is the one for the sphere (be it an infinite one).